# Python - MongoDB Queries Multiple Issues

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm having multiple issues running the below Python script. In the getStudentGrade function I get the following error:
("cannot set options after executing query")
pymongo.errors.InvalidOperation: cannot set options after executing query

If I comment out the section of that function that's the issue (the elif statements) I get this error:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

I think it's related to the addScore function, but I've tried all kinds of combos and no go. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

#Note to run the following code you will need to import the grades.js file

client = MongoClient("localhost", 27017)
db = client['test']

exam_type = u'exam'
quiz_type = u'quiz'
homework_type = u'homework'
####Note: Python enforces space, so ensure that each line of your code is in line with
####        the line above it.
####Note: Only modify this file. Put code in after the line ######### YOUR CODE STARTS HERE ################

def addScore(student_id,score_type,score):
    scoreId = None
    # Insert a score document into the mod6 collection of the test database.
    # Place the id returned from id into the scoreId variable.
    ######### YOUR CODE STARTS HERE ################
    scoreId = db.mod6.insert({"student_id":student_id, "type":score_type, "score":score})
    ######### YOUR CODE ENDS HERE ################
    return  scoreId

def updateScore(scoreId,student_id,score_type,score):
    result = None
    # Update the score document with the "_id" field of scoreId
    # , so that it has the student id, score_type, and score from the function arguments.
    # Place the id returned from id into the scoreId variable.
    ######### YOUR CODE STARTS HERE ################
    result = db.mod6.update({"_id":scoreId},{"student_id":student_id,"type":score_type,"score":score}, False, False)
    ######### YOUR CODE ENDS HERE ################
    return  result

def retrieveOneScore(student_id, score_type):
    result = None
    # Retrieve one score from the mod6 collection for a specific student with the student id field set
    #   to the passed student_id argument of the type of the second argument
    ######### YOUR CODE STARTS HERE ################
    results = db.mod6.find_one({"student_id":student_id, "type":score_type})
    ######### YOUR CODE ENDS HERE ################
    return  result

def retrieveAllScores(student_id, score_type):
    results = None
    # Retrieve all scores from the mod6 collection for a specific student with the student id field set
    #   to the passed student_id argument of the type of the second argument
    ######### YOUR CODE STARTS HERE ################
    results = db.mod6.find({"student_id":student_id, "type":score_type})
    ######### YOUR CODE ENDS HERE ################
    return  results

def average(results):
    avg = 0
    # Average all of the score values in the results variable and place in the avg variable
    ######### YOUR CODE STARTS HERE ################
    num_results = 0
    total_score = 0
    for result in results:
        num_results += 1
        total_score += int(result[u'score'])
    average_score = total_score/num_results
    ######### YOUR CODE ENDS HERE ################
    return avg

def getStudentGrade(student_id):
    result = None
    # You will need to retrieve a specific student's (student_id argument) and weight the average
    # values for the different grade types (exam 50% of final grade, quiz 30% of final grade, 
    #   homework 20% of final grade) and then add them and place in the result variable
    # Note: It may be obvious but the resulting score should be from 0 - 100.
    ######### YOUR CODE STARTS HERE ################
    results = db.mod6.find({"student_id":student_id})
    eweight = 50
    qweight = 30
    hweight = 20
    quiztotal = 0
    examtotal = 0
    homeworktotal = 0
    for result in results:
        if(result[u'type'] == "quiz"):
            quiztotal += int(result[u'score']) * qweight
        #elif(results[u'type'] == "exam"):
        #   examtotal += int(result[u'score']) * eweight
        #elif(results[u'type'] == homework):
        #   homeworktotal += int(result[u'score']) * hweight


    ######### YOUR CODE ENDS HERE ################
    return  result

def test_all_methods():
    result = []
    exam_scores = [82,92]
    quiz_scores = [95,72,85]
    homework_scores = [35, 90, 78]
    student_id = 200
    for exam_score in exam_scores:
        temp_result = addScore(student_id,exam_type,exam_score)
        result.append(temp_result)
    for quiz_score in quiz_scores:
        temp_result = addScore(student_id,quiz_type,quiz_score)
        result.append(temp_result)
    for homework_score in homework_scores:
        temp_result = addScore(student_id,homework_type,homework_score)
        result.append(temp_result)
    result.append(retrieveOneScore(student_id, quiz_type))
    result.append(retrieveAllScores(student_id, homework_type))
    result.append(average(result[9]))
    result.append(getStudentGrade(student_id))
    return result
```

Comment: `results = db.mod6.find({"student_id":student_id})` returned more than one value or returned none. Need check `if exists` maybe returned `None`. So  `results = db.mod6.find({"student_id":student_id})`add next condition `if len(results) == 1 :`

Comment: I'll give that a shot. What about the insert issue?

Comment: `ID` is important when you got same data pattern. Write method is your reading method. Who accept a lot data when calling only one ? Server (sql) like `big-data` query cos don't waste resources. You need unique `id` when you got same data pattern(For fast response). Will be call big tree parts every query if you haven't unique `ID`.